# How can I do that when the home view navigates to the login view, trigger the useEffect of the login?

Tags: reactjs

Basically in `login` I have a function that verifies if a token exists, and if it exists automatically redirects to the`home` view, otherwise it will remain in the `login` view.

Login

```
const Login = props => {
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); 

   useEffect(() => {
    getTokenPrevious();
   }, [loading]);


    const getTokenPrevious = () => {
    AsyncStorage.multiGet(["token"])
        .then(value => {
            let token = value[0][1];

            if (token !== null) {
                props.navigation.navigate("home");
            } else {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            setLoading(false);
        });
   };


   if (loading) {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
                <Text>Loading...</Text>
                <Spinner color={STYLES.bgHeader.backgroundColor} />
            </View>
        );
    }

  return (
    rest code login....
```

Sometimes when from the `home` view I use the`backbutton` of the cell phone or when I try to tap on the `logout` button, this redirects me to the`login` view but this part is shown:

```
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
                <Text>Loading...</Text>
                <Spinner color={STYLES.bgHeader.backgroundColor} />
            </View>
        );
```

the part that should be shown is this:

```
  return (
    rest code login....
```

because the token no longer exists because it was deleted.

home

```
const Home= props => {

 clearStorage = () => {
 AsyncStorage.removeItem("token")
  .then(() => {
    props.navigation.navigate("Login");
  })

 };

 return (
 <View>
  <Button onPress={clearStorage()} ><Text>Logout</Text></Button>
 <View>
 )
}
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Can you add codesandbox?

Comment: I cant, but that pieces is the most important, this represents my problem

Comment: Just a basic code, you can replace you logic with dummy code.

Comment: what navigation library do you use? react-navigation?

Answer (score 3):

`<Button onPress={clearStorage()} ><Text>Logout</Text></Button>`

clearStorage() call the method, When If loaded.
remove the () from clearStorgae.

`<Button onPress={clearStorage} ><Text>Logout</Text></Button>`

Answer (score 0):

`onPress` property of `Button` component is set to a Promise and not a function.

This will cause a loop back to the `Login` view whenever `Home` view is loaded because `clearStorage` function is being invoked when registering `onPress` handler.

The correction to make there is:

```
 <Button onPress={clearStorage}><Text>Logout</Text></Button>
```

In addition, the registered effect is skipped on re-render if value of `loading` doesn't change.

*For your use case, whether the effect runs or not shouldn't be dependent on the value of the `loading` state*.

Typically, you want to run the effect when the user isn't authorized, *i.e* when email and token are not set. One can make the assumption that when the component is mounted, both are not set.

I recommend to set the second argument to `useEffect` hook to be an empty array. This keeps the effect from being invoked between re-renders. This is akin to side effect implemented in `componentDidMount` method of a React class.

```
const Login = props => {
   //...

   useEffect(() => {
    getTokenPrevious();
   }, []);
```

<s>You may want to run `getTokenPrevious` effect every time `Login` renders as I currently do not see a need for skipping this particular effect</s>.

<s>I recommend to leave out the second argument *set the second argument passed to `useEffect`* to an empty array and always check that a token is there **when the component is first mounted**.</s>

```
 useEffect(() => {
    getTokenPrevious();
 });
```

Comment: thanks! but in the `Login`, `getTokenPrevious();` is executed infinite tymes causes a type of loop  when my app starts https://i.imgur.com/haP09Jg.jpg

Comment: I checked in the screenshot that you have shared and I'll update my answer with additional recommendations

Comment: I add [] to useEffect... when go Home to Login, nothing happens... useEffect  is not triggered

Comment: That's seems to be happening because Login component is mounted already. When you navigate from Home to Login, what changed about the state of the Login component?

Comment: Exactly, that's my problem. I don't know what you can recommend me, so that when I redirect from `home` to `login` "something" happens to activate the `getTokenPrevious` function