# How can I make a function run every time I enter the component, using the useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want the function that detects if there is a saved token to be verified, every time the component called `login` is executed.In `login` I have a function that verifies if a token exists, and if it exists automatically redirects to the`home` view, otherwise it will remain in the `login` view.

Login

```
const Login = props => {
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); 

   useEffect(() => {
    getTokenPrevious();
   }, [loading]);


    const getTokenPrevious = () => {
    AsyncStorage.multiGet(["token"])
        .then(value => {
            let token = value[0][1];

            if (token !== null) {
                props.navigation.navigate("home");
            } else {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            setLoading(false);
        });
   };


   if (loading) {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
                <Text>Loading...</Text>
                <Spinner color={STYLES.bgHeader.backgroundColor} />
            </View>
        );
    }

  return (
    rest code login....
```

Sometimes when from the `home` view I use the`backbutton` of the cell phone or when I try to tap on the `logout` button, this redirects me to the`login` view but this part is shown:

```
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
                <Text>Loading...</Text>
                <Spinner color={STYLES.bgHeader.backgroundColor} />
            </View>
        );
```

the part that should be shown is this:

```
  return (
    rest code login....
```

because the token no longer exists because it was deleted.

home

```
const Home= props => {

 clearStorage = () => {
 AsyncStorage.removeItem("token")
  .then(() => {
    props.navigation.navigate("Login");
  })

 };

 return (
 <View>
  <Button onPress={clearStorage()} ><Text>Logout</Text></Button>
 <View>
 )
}
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Why are you passing `[loading]` into `useEffect`? Are you sure `getTokenPrevious` is being run to set `loading` to false?

Comment: Take a look at this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/function-after-focusing-screen.html

Comment: @CameronDowner `getTokenPrevious ` it does it the first time, when I return to my component the `useEffect()` does not run again. I really put "loading" in the useState to see if it worked, but when I return from home nothing happens with loading, `useEffect` is not called

Comment: My suspicion is that it's being caused by that `[loading]`, have you tried removing that second parameter completely?

Comment: yes, nothing new ocurrs

Comment: Is it possible to get a small, repeatable example on a code sandbox?

Comment: @CameronDowner I exposed the most relevant. My problem is that I don't know how to make the variable `loading` (or I don't know which is the best way), it will be reloaded when returning from the` home` view to `loading` to make the `useEffect` run

Comment: @yavg are you using ract-navigation, right? Why don't use navigation events?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do that when the home view navigates to the login view, trigger the useEffect of the login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59367698/how-can-i-do-that-when-the-home-view-navigates-to-the-login-view-trigger-the-us)

Answer (score -2):

Even if you have deleted the token, this change will not be reflected in `Login` component, therefore `loading` will sitll be `true` and that's why `useEffect` is not called. Try listening `didFocus` or `willFocus` event on `Login` component and check again if token exists

```
useEffect(()=>{
    getTokenPrevious()
    const focusListener = props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
        getTokenPrevious()
    })
    return ()=>focusListener.remove()
},[])
```

Instead of

```
useEffect(() => {
    getTokenPrevious();
}, [loading]);
```