# Checking the checkbox in a list does not render again in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to change its value when you click on a checkbox. But for some reason the changes are not rendered again. why?

[image]

sample data (props.data):

```
    {
        "school": {
            "checkDocuments": [
                {
                    'label': 'license',
                    'check': false
                },
                {
                    'label': 'identification',
                    'check': false
                },
                {
                    'label': 'phone',
                    'check': false
                },

            ],
            "section": "escuela"
        },

        "collage": {
            "checkDocuments": [
                {
                    'label': 'license',
                    'check': false
                }
            ],
            "section": "universidad"
    }
```

this is my component:

```
export const Verificardocuments = props => {

    const [documents, setDocuments] = useState(props.data);

    updateDataDocument = (section, index) => {
      console.log(section, index);
      documents[section].checkDocuments[index].check = 
      !documents[section].checkDocuments[index].check;
      setDocuments(documents);
    }

   return 
    <List>

    {
        /* escuela,universidad  => "section" key */
        Object.keys(documents).map((section, i) => {

            return (
                <View key={i}>
                    <ListItem itemDivider >
                        <Text>{documents[section].section}</Text>
                    </ListItem>

                    {documents[section].checkDocuments.map((document, j) => {
                        return (
                            <ListItem onPress={() => updateDataDocument(section, j)} key={j} >
                                <CheckBox checked={document.check} color="blue" />
                                <Body>
                                    <Text>{document.label}</Text>
                                </Body>
                            </ListItem>)
                    })}
                </View>
            )

        })
    }
    </List>
 }
```

I am not sure if I am doing the best way to update an element contained in my array.

Comment: You are mutating your state variable directly. Don't do that. Instead, create a local copy of documents inside updateDataDocument, mutate the copy, and set the new state to be the copy.

Comment: @Chris Sorry, I want to learn. We could lend a hand with your explanation, I'm starting in the world of react.. please

Comment: No worries, I've explained what I mean in my answer below. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

Since your data structure is somewhat complex/big, you need to create a copy for every nested object or array within. Once that is done, you can safely update the copy without also changing the original variable (the state). Then, with the copy being updated to how you want the new state to be, you simply use it to set the new state.

```
updateDataDocument = (section, index) => {
  const obj = {...documents}; // Copy the documents object
  const arr = [...obj[section].checkDocuments] // Copy the checkDocuments array
  const item = {...arr[index]} // Copy the item inside the array
  item.check = !item.check; // Change the value
  arr[index] = item;
  obj[section].checkDocuments = arr;
  setDocuments(obj);
}
```

Another way, which effectively is the same thing, is how @AsafAviv did it.

Comment: hey, thanks.. your answer is more clear, I am getting this error https://i.imgur.com/DStmBx3.jpg

Comment: I'm new, I'm trying to solve it, if you make it before me please tell me how

Comment: @yavg sorry forgot one step. Try it again

Comment: thanks, can you help me please? I have a bounty https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59367698/how-can-i-do-that-when-the-home-view-navigates-to-the-login-view-trigger-the-us

Answer (score 1):

State updates in function components must be immutable.

It is recommended to use the callback pattern when updating objects inside the state and spread each object to avoid losing the rest of the properties

```js
updateDataDocument = (section, index) => {
  setDocuments(prevState => ({
    // spread the previous state into a new object
    ...prevState,
    [section]: {
      // also spread prevState[section] into a new object
      ...prevState[section],
      // create a new array of checkDocuments
      checkDocuments: prevState[section].checkDocuments.map((doc, i) =>
        i === index
          ? // when we find the object we need to update,
            // spread it into a new object and then update
            // the check property
            { ...doc, check: !doc.check }
          : doc
      ),
    },
  }))
}
```

Nested immutable updates are ugly and it might be better to introduce an immutable library that will handle it for you such as [immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) which have a [hooks version](https://github.com/immerjs/use-immer) which lets you update the state in a mutable way

```js
import { useImmer } from 'use-immer'

export const Verificardocuments = props => {
  const [documents, setDocuments] = useImmer(props.data);

  const updateDataDocument = (section, index) => {
    setDocuments(draft => {
      const prevChecked = draft[section].checkDocuments[index].check
      draft[section].checkDocuments[index].check = !prevChecked
    })
  }

  return ...
}
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/HuHxALp I think I understand what you did .. but I have a strange problem

Comment: @yavg Yes my bad i used `...prevState.section` instead of `...prevState[section]`, fixed.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. The other answer was easier for me to understand. Friend I see that you know a lot, I have an open bounty, nobody has been able to give me a solution, I thank you if you can help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59367698/how-can-i-do-that-when-the-home-view-navigates-to-the-login-view-trigger-the-us

Comment: @yavg You're welcome, I understand that Chris's answer is indeed easier to understand and it's perfectly fine to accept other answers especially when they indeed solve the problem :). It's just another way of solving it

Comment: I will consider your syntax for another scenario. I hope you can help me with my other question.

Answer (score -1):

`documents` is being mutated that's why it doesn't trigger re-render. so i advise to assign it to a local copy and do the mutation there

```
updateDataDocument = (section, index) => {
  const newDoc = documents
  newDoc[section].checkDocuments[index].check = !newDoc[section].checkDocuments[index].check;
  setDocuments(newDoc)
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error with `setDocuments(...documents)` https://i.imgur.com/ls0NiJe.jpg

Comment: This is *not* creating a local copy. The idea is correct, the execution isn't.